# How do I play a 16⅔ RPM record?

Tags: history, vinyl, equipment

I bought an LP record from a local library and back home turned it on to hear it. And I get very funny voice like somebody is on helium.

I thought I had it on 45 and wanted to switch to 33, but it *was* on 33. After some fiddling with my player thinking something is wrong with it, I still hear the fast speaking. Then I look at the label it says 16⅔. I have never heard of such a thing!

Is there any way one can still play this record on a turntable that only has 33 and 45 speeds, or should I try to find something even more ancient that also has 16⅔? I thought my equipment was tyrannosaurus-age, but there is clearly something that predates that!

Comment: I am old and I have seen many record players over the years but I have only once seen one which offered 16 2/3.  They might have been common in some specialist areas but not in the general population.  My brother sometimes played 33 1/3 records at 16 2/3 to practice guitar riffs as it neatly an octave down.

Comment: @badjohn Interesting!

Comment: When I was (much!) younger my sister and I had a cheap (as in, enclosure made of heavy cardboard+contact paper)  portable record player with a 16-2/3 speed.  I think we had one record that played at that speed, but I mostly used it to make funny noises.  Anyway, this speed was available on at least some mass market consumer grade devices in the 1960s.

Comment: I had a lovely radiogram that had the record player able to spin at 16 2/3, 33, 45 and 78. It was a relatively common make of radiogram back in the late 60s, early 70s. Wish I still had it - the radio and amp sections were wonderful.

Answer (score 19):

While 16⅔ RPM might be rare, some DJ turntables have a pitch adjustment going as low as -50% (also known as ultrapitch). Note that "33" is really 33⅓, so 16⅔ is exactly half of it. A turntable set to "33" with pitch -50% would play the record correctly. But that might be an expensive way just to play one record.

Consider playing back the record at 33 speed, recording it on a computer, and slowing it down by 50%. You can do it using a free editor such as Audacity.

Comment: Record the sound/music as .wav, or .mp3 file with 33 rpm, and then use [timestretch](https://29a.ch/timestretch/) to adjust the either the pace, or the pitch, or pace and pitch without installation from your web browser works well enough (e.g., training touch typing) for this successor of [playitslowly](https://29a.ch/playitslowly), too.  It equally has an optional export to .mp3 of the processed data.

Comment: @Buttonwood If you're going to manipulate a sound file, and have the choice, *always* start with a lossless format (e.g. WAV or FLAC). MP3 (and other common formats like Vorbis, AAC, etc) works by *approximating* the recorded sound, discarding information which you're unlikely to notice when playing it back. If you then time-stretch that approximation, the differences between the real sound and the approximation may become more obvious. (The same rule applies to images - always keep a lossless copy if possible, and only export to JPEG after you're finished editing.)

Comment: @IMSoP I agree .wav is the the better option than .mp3, and timestretch in the instance on the web equally accepts the former format (just successfully checked again with a commercial [audio CD](https://www.fnac.com/a1366962/Maxime-Le-Forestier-Plutot-guitare-CD-album) pressed by polydor in 2002). As for digital photos, it would be an interesting separate question how many individual .jpg are required to obtain a better signal/noise ratio by arithmetical mean vs [median stacking](https://petapixel.com/2013/05/29/a-look-at-reducing-noise-in-photographs-using-median-blending/), or lucky imaging.

Comment: in astro photography (the later obviously is much more than only computing a mean value per pixel, https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucky_Imaging).

Answer (score 17):

You need something more ancient or actually, more specialist.

To give longer playback times, spoken word was often cut at 16 2/3, or even 8 1/3. Radio stations used to use them for pre-recorded shows. Even back in the 50s/60s most record players weren't capable of those speeds [33, 45, 78 would be common].

Refs: [Wikipedia - Phonograph Record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonograph_record)
& [BloggerRhythms - Slower Than Slow: 16 RPM Records](https://bloggerhythms.blogspot.com/2011/05/slower-than-slow-16-rpm-records.html)

Comment: As I wrote in a comment, DJ equipment with 33 speed and -50% pitch range is available (but might be relatively expensive), and that would cover 16 2/3. But 8 1/3 would be indeed rare!

Comment: WOW! I've learned something new!

Comment: Apparently they were also for [car stereos](https://obsoletemedia.org/16rpm-lp/)!

Comment: Back in the '60s, my neighbour had a radiogram which I used, to learn numbers from, as they played near enough half speed for 33rpm LPs. So slow enough to decipher what was going on.

Comment: My father had some 16 2/3 records when I was a kid - they were spoken comedy.  From, I dunno, maybe the early 50s?  There were record players back then (this would be the late 60s) that could play them, but most would only do 78/45/33.3̅.

Comment: More ancient, perhaps, but not really "specialized".  The first two turntables I ever owned--acquired used in the early 1970s--both used vacuum tubes for amplification, and offered four-way 16/33/45/78 selections.  One was a folding changer unit, I think by Sears, and the other was a non-changer unit, but both seemed like mass-market consumer units.  From what I recall of the designs, the only cost difference for having four speeds instead of three would be a need to machine a fourth diameter on the motor spindle where the rubber wheel would press against it.  The biggest...

Comment: ...issue I would expect with finding such a thing would be that many such units may have been discarded if the rubber wheels got lumpy, even though I think replacing the wheels would not be difficult.

Comment: I've only ever seen one, back in the 60s. An aunt had one we used to play 45s at 16, because that's the kind of thing that amuses an 8-year-old ;) By the time I owned my first 'valve Dansette' in the early 70s it would only play 33 & 45, even 78 had gone. By the time I worked in broadcasting, 80s, all this type of old stuff was long gone.

Comment: Actually almost all cheap turntables sold at least into the mid 1980's could do 16 RPM. They did 16, 33, 45, and 78.

Comment: @David42 Really? My parent's turntable only had 33, 45, and 78, and I'm pretty sure it was cheap :) (Granted, it was purchased in the early 70s, maybe 16 was an option added later?)

Comment: @Tetsujin: Proper playback of most 78RPM records required the use of a different stylus from playback of newer records.  The 78RPM disk was standardized at a time before electronic amplification, when a record needle would need to move a diaphragm with enough force to produce adequate sound power directly (record players would have a horn for impedance matching, but the horn couldn't output more power than the diaphragm received from the needle).  Records were thus designed to be played with a soft steel needle, which was expected to wear down faster than records played with it.

Comment: @supercat - completely unrelated to the question or answer. Plus, back in the 60s & before, few people knew or cared. Record player needles were generally double-sided, flippable. Some people would actually make the effort to use the correct side… others didn't. It was a low-tech society back then.

Comment: @Tetsujin: For some reason, I misread the comment to which I replied as having dropped support for 78 but not 16.  Since speed control mechanisms could have added a few more speeds without increasing complexity, the discontinuance of support for 78 would have a different motiviation from the discontinuance of support for 16.

Comment: If I recall correctly, one of the uses of 16 was for language courses (Linguaphone comes to mind). I have seen a record player with 16 available but can't remember what, where or exactly when.

Answer (score 4):

If you have access to a manual or some online resources for your record player, you should be able to find a speed adjustment screw somewhere on the unit. I'm sure it differs greatly from unit to unit, but on mine, it requires a fairly precision flathead screwdriver to turn it. Turning the screw clockwise should raise the speed on all settings, and counterclockwise should slow it down.

You can use a strobe or turntable rpm app to fine-tune it to run at 16 2/3 when set at 33. The purpose of the screw is to correct the rpm in cases of it becoming off, so I wouldn't fiddle around with it too much outside of its designed purpose.

Hope this helps.

Comment: More than half of the vinyl players are simply locked to the grid frequency (50 Hz or 60 Hz) and no adjustment is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Play it at 33 1/3 to your PC, record it as a WAV file or similar.

Then use Audacity or other sound editor to replay that at half speed.

Probably a lot easier than trying to find a Goldring-Lenco GL75 or other turntable with a 16 2/3 rpm speed setting.

Answer (score 1):

Every turntable that used a synchronous AC drive motor (that is, almost every one made until about 1975) would be line-locked for speed to the mains frequency. Speed changing was done by means of a simple transmission between the platter and the motor and the default turntable transmission all the way up to about 1970 was a four-speed with a 16 2/3 RPM "granny gear", mechanically selected with a little lever.

At the point where mass-market synchronous AC platter drives with mechanical transmissions were replaced by DC servo drives (beginning in about 1976), the 16 2/3 and 78 RPM formats were obsolete for mass market vinyl and turntable manufacturers began omitting them in favor of two-speed (33 1/3 and 45 RPM) drives.

Comment: Thanks for this useful info!